# Is there an easy way to color pick pixel with bigger sample?

Tags: python

This is a question that I had for quite a while and surprisingly no body else seems to be asking this question.

In Photoshop, when pixel sampling color picker, I could specify 1x1, 3x3, or 5x5 samples. Basically averaging color based on that area.

I am not sure if Blender Color Picker can already do this, but I would like to be able to do this using Python.

I am aware of this one:
[How to get screen color under mouse cursor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70808/how-to-get-screen-color-under-mouse-cursor)

But that is a little bit over complex. All I need is sampling pixel color from area in 2D View and then store the data in the buffer to paste.

Comment: From the code at above link, I realized there is this "c" value which has this: Buffer(GL_FLOAT, [[0.22352942824363708], [0.22352942824363708], [0.22352942824363708]])

And I am not sure how to get the RGB from that Buffer.

But anyhow on top of that, I am wondering still if we can get bigger sampling area and average the pixels within the area.

Comment: col = c.to_list()
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].color = (col[0][0], col[1][0], col[2][0], 1.0)