# How can I activate various eyedroppers using script

Tags: python, scripting, selection-tools, tools

Now, in order to find an eyedropper I have to click a tiny button, scroll, click another tiny button, click the eyedropper, and THEN I can finally pick a color. I'm aware that with 'E' I can shorten this path a tiny bit, but I would just want a single key-combi for every single eyedropper. ONE CLICK to get the color should be more than enough.

However... I've tried a lot of things now and I can't get it to work.
The first thing was copying the python-tip of an eyedropper (((  ***bpy.ops.ui.eyedropper_color()***   ))) into the console and later into a simple script.
But both come back with {'PASS_THROUGH'}.

I've also tried to put it in a simple Modal Operator, but that gives back *nothing*.
(I've tried it alone in various places, and in this script here in different places simultaneously. With and without these additions of 'invoke default' etc)

```
import bpy


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

def __init__(self):
    print("Start")

def __del__(self):
    print("End")

def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.ui.eyedropper_color('EXEC_DEFAULT')
    
    return {'FINISHED'}

def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':  # Apply
        self.value = event.mouse_x
        self.execute(context)
    elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':  # Confirm
        bpy.ops.ui.eyedropper_color('EXEC_DEFAULT')
        return {'FINISHED'}
    elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:  # Cancel
        context.object.location.x = self.init_loc_x
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    bpy.ops.ui.eyedropper_color('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    self.init_loc_x = context.object.location.x
    self.value = event.mouse_x
    self.execute(context)

    context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)

# test call
bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

There's also 2 different home-made eyedropper-like-things floating around as far as I've seen.
here: https://blenderartists.org/t/pick-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-the-image-editor/575317
and here: (shit I've lost the link, will update if I find it again)

But I can't get them to work. They seem to run without crashes, but they don't do anything for me. Nothing changes. And as I can't fully understand what's happening in them yet, I don't know if this could be part of the solution.

I've also searched a little in the source code, and found this piece of code that's in most of the eyedroppers (at least similar):

```
/* identifiers */
ot->name = "Eyedropper";
ot->idname = "UI_OT_eyedropper_color";
ot->description = "Sample a color from the Blender window to store in a property";

/* api callbacks */
ot->invoke = eyedropper_invoke;
ot->modal = eyedropper_modal;
ot->cancel = eyedropper_cancel;
ot->exec = eyedropper_exec;
ot->poll = eyedropper_poll;
```

This seems like a way to interact with the API, but I don't know how and if I could use this exactly.

If someone has anything that might even just lead to a partial solution, I'm all ear!

Comment: A year has passed, do find any solution yet?

Comment: No, I gave up after a few days of searching

Comment: Oh, that hurts.  Thank for reply.   I can printscreen and save as texture using script ( https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-2-9-bgl-readpixels-has-strange-offset-region/1286487    and https://developer.blender.org/T85885  ) .   Perhaps (not test), I can read the correct pixel using script in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70808/how-to-get-screen-color-under-mouse-cursor and https://devtalk.blender.org/t/mouse-position-on-gride-view/6095 .  Just sharing.